# Write computed setter as a public function

Tags: typescript, vue.js, methods

I came across [Computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) in vue and I find it very useful. For the sake of completeness I shall copy and paste the code snippet here.

```
// ...
computed: {
  fullName: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      var names = newValue.split(' ')
      this.firstName = names[0]
      this.lastName = names[names.length - 1]
    }
  }
}
// ...
```

This works perfectly in my case. The only issue is have the same block over several components, and I don't really like that. What I would prefer is to define a method something like `GetOrSetFullName(newValue)` and then in the components simply call the method something like

```
// ...
computed: {
  fullName: GetOrSetFullName(newValue);
}
// ...
```

Is that possible or are there other standardized procedures on how to avoid duplicated code blocks over several components?

NOTE: In case it matters. Code above is copy pasted from vue webpage, but I am using typescript.

Comment: The value of `fullName` is a plain object, so you can just call a function that returns that plain object.

Comment: @VLAZ Did you notice the getter and setter functions inside? I need them both to work.

Comment: Right, and you return an object with the same functions assigned to `get` and `set`. Again, it's just a plain object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define the getter/setter in a separate object and reuse it to your heart's content:

```js
const fullNameComputer = {
  get: function() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    var names = value.split(' ');
    this.firstName = names[0];
    this.lastName = names[names.length - 1];
  }
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Bar'
  },
  computed: {
    fullName: fullNameComputer
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model.lazy="fullName">
  <br>
  {{ fullName }}
</div>
```